# chart.js-plugin-annotations multiple vertical lines on reoccuring values

Tags: chartjs-2.6.0

I am using chart.js 2.6 and chart.js-plugin-annotations 0.5.5 to create a graph.

```
data["22:00","00:00","02:00","04:00","06:00","08:00","10:00","12:00","14:00","16:00","18:00","20:00","22:00","00:00","02:00"]
```

I would like to have an annotiation on every occurance of "00:00" to show the end of the day. I tried to have 2 annotiations but both seem to be align with the first appearance of "00:00".

```
annotation: {
    annotations: [
        {
            type                : "line",
            mode                : "vertical",
            scaleID             : "x-axis-0",
            value               : "00:00",
            borderColor         : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",               
        },
        {
            type                : "line",
            mode                : "vertical",
            scaleID             : "x-axis-0",
            value               : "00:00",
            borderColor         : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",               
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: This can't be done using **chartjs-plugin-annotation**. You might need to create your **own** plugin.

Comment: I think that you can only draw a vertical line on a value that also exists in the labels. In data[] you have a time, label is it maybe a date. So the value of the annotation must be the value of the associated label.

Comment: Here is an example of multiple vertical annotations: 
http://jsfiddle.net/g0v2wap5/10/